# PC won't detect microphone after being plugged in

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, microphone, input

I am tasked with configuring multiple microphones on Dell 5060 Optiplexes via the 3,5mm headphone jack in **Windows 10**.

The weird thing is that some Optiplexes **do** detect the microphone input via Windows Sound panel (visible as **Jack Mic**) while other Optiplexes display **no input devices found**.

What I have tried:

- Trying to connect and reconnect the microphone (even on other ports)
- Reinstalling the Realtek audio drivers
- Disable Exclusivity mode in Windows
- Double checked if Microphone Access was enabled

What I have noticed:

- The Optiplexes that DO work display a pop-up window asking which input has been connected (that is something non-functioning Optiplexes won't do)
- The Realtek drivers of the functioning Optiplexes are: 10.0.17134.1
- The Realtek drivers of the non-functioning Optiplexes are: 10.0.17763.1

Is there something that I can still do to make the 3,5mm microphones work? It's very strange since some Optiplexes do seem to work....

Comment: I'd definitely try get hold of the older drivers - if your results are that specific, it would seem the obvious first test.

Comment: Just tried a roll back but that made the disabled Jack Mic input disappear on it's own. So that is definitely not a solution sadly.

Comment: Also get the Waves Maxx audio program, see your model in Dell support for the download.  Install from this from the MS store, then reinstall the Realtek drivers.  This has worked for me with Dell Latitudes that won't see the headset inserted.

Comment: I have tried to activate the input device from Waves Maxx audio program but that does not reactivate the Jack Mic input device. I have also tried older audio drivers but to no avail.